# Making caramel on glass top stoves

Tags: caramel

Why can't I make caramel or toffee on my glass topped stove?  I have tried different pans, different thermometers, stirring, not stirring, different recipes, different temperatures.  It turns out scorched, rock hard, or, in the case of toffee, it separates.  I used to make good caramel on my old electric stove.

Comment: What's the actual heating process? You can get glass topped induction, halogen, resistive etc. I suspect it's resistive and responds more slowly than your previous cooker.  Was that the coiled glowing sort?

Comment: I have one halogen burner, the rest are resistive.  I've tried it on both.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to make the caramel?  Using only sugar, put it in the pan over a high heat and stir continuously.  It will start to crystallize, and even form crystals up the side of the pan, but be patient, it will caramelize. There really shouldn't be an issue, I use a glass topped stove, normally with a heavy based stainless pan.